# Run sp_msforeachdb to select dbsize used in c#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a query as such:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
'USE [?]; 
SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Database Name], 
    CAST(SUM(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed''))/128.0 AS decimal(18,2)) AS [Used space(MB)]
FROM sys.database_files
Where type_desc = ''ROWS'' and
GROUP BY type_desc'
```

and executing this in MSSM is alright.

My problem is that I need to execute this in my application using c# and stored in a `Datatable`. Any idea how to do this?

Tried looking for at `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and `CommandType.Text`but still can't figure it out.

FYI, I'm not allowed to create a new stored procedure for this.

### EDIT (SAMPLE CODE)

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(HoustonSqlCon))
                {
                    const string query = "EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; SELECT DB_NAME() AS[Database Name]," +
                                         "CAST(SUM(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'')) / 128.0 AS decimal(18, 2)) AS[Used space(MB)]" +
                                         "FROM sys.database_files" +
                                         "Where type_desc = ''ROWS''" +
                                         "GROUP BY type_desc'";

                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        sqlConnection.Open();
                        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                       adapter.Fill(totalSchemas);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: the 'and' before GROUP BY should be removed

Comment: @NolanShang thanks for pointing tht out